# What's the probability distribution of a deterministic signal or how to marginalize dynamical systems?

Tags: mathematical-physics, probability, integration, signal-processing, non-linear-systems

In many signal processing calculations, the (prior) probability distribution of the theoretical signal (not the signal + noise) is required.

In random signal theory, this distribution is typically a stochastic process, e.g. a Gaussian or a uniform process.

What do such distributions become in deterministic signal theory?, that is the question.

To make it simple, consider a discrete-time real deterministic signal

$ s\left( {1} \right),s\left( {2} \right),...,s\left( {M} \right) $

For instance, they may be samples from a continuous-time real deterministic signal.

By the standard definition of a discrete-time deterministic dynamical system, there exists:

- a phase space $\Gamma$, e.g. $\Gamma  \subset  \mathbb{R} {^d}$
- an initial condition $ z\left( 1 \right)\in \Gamma $
- a state-space equation $f:\Gamma  \to \Gamma $ such as $z\left( {m + 1} \right) = f\left[ {z\left( m \right)} \right]$
- an output or observation equation $g:\Gamma  \to \mathbb{R}$ such as $s\left( m \right) = g\left[ {z\left( m \right)} \right]$

Hence, by definition we have

$\left[ {s\left( 1 \right),s\left( 2 \right),...,s\left( M \right)} \right] = \left\{ {g\left[ {z\left( 1 \right)} \right],g\left[ {f\left( {z\left( 1 \right)} \right)} \right],...,g\left[ {{f^{M - 1}}\left( {z\left( 1 \right)} \right)} \right]} \right\}$

or, in probabilistic notations

$p\left[ {\left. {s\left( 1 \right),s\left( 2 \right),...,s\left( M \right)} \right|z\left( 1 \right),f,g,\Gamma ,d} \right] = \prod\limits_{m = 1}^M {\delta \left\{ {g\left[ {{f^{m - 1}}\left( {z\left( 1 \right)} \right)} \right] - s\left( m \right)} \right\}} $

Therefore, by total probability and the product rule, the marginal joint prior probability distribution for a discrete-time deterministic signal conditional on phase space $\Gamma$ and its dimension $d$ formally/symbolically writes

$p\left[ {\left. {s\left( 1 \right),s\left( 2 \right),...,s\left( M \right)} \right|\Gamma ,d} \right] = \int\limits_{{\mathbb{R}^\Gamma }} {\int\limits_{{\Gamma ^\Gamma }} {\int\limits_\Gamma  {{\text{D}}g{\text{D}}f{{\text{d}}^d}z\left( 1 \right)\prod\limits_{m = 1}^M {\delta \left\{ {g\left[ {{f^{m - 1}}\left( {z\left( 1 \right)} \right)} \right] - s\left( m \right)} \right\}p\left( {z\left( 1 \right),f,g} \right)} } } } $

Should phase space $\Gamma$ and its dimension $d$ be also unknown *a priori*, they should be marginalized as well so that the most general marginal prior probability distribution for a deterministic signal I'm interested in formally/symbolically writes

$p\left[ {s\left( 1 \right),s\left( 2 \right),...,s\left( M \right)} \right] = \sum\limits_{d = 2}^{ + \infty } {\int\limits_{\wp \left( {{\mathbb{R}^d}} \right)} {\int\limits_{{\mathbb{R}^\Gamma }} {\int\limits_{{\Gamma ^\Gamma }} {\int\limits_\Gamma  {{\text{D}}\Gamma {\text{D}}g{\text{D}}f{{\text{d}}^d}z\left( 1 \right)\prod\limits_{m = 1}^M {\delta \left\{ {g\left[ {{f^{m - 1}}\left( {z\left( 1 \right)} \right)} \right] - s\left( m \right)} \right\}p\left( {z\left( 1 \right),f,g,\Gamma ,d} \right)} } } } } } $

where ${\wp \left( {{\mathbb{R}^d}} \right)}$ stands for the powerset of ${{\mathbb{R}^d}}$.

Dirac's $\delta$ distributions are certainly welcome to "digest" those very high dimensional integrals. However, we may also be interested in probability distributions like

$p\left[ {s\left( 1 \right),s\left( 2 \right),...,s\left( M \right)} \right] \propto \sum\limits_{d = 2}^{ + \infty } {\int\limits_{\wp \left( {{\mathbb{R}^d}} \right)} {\int\limits_{{\mathbb{R}^\Gamma }} {\int\limits_{{\Gamma ^\Gamma }} {\int\limits_\Gamma  {\int\limits_{{\mathbb{R}^ + }} {{\text{D}}\Gamma {\text{D}}g{\text{D}}f{{\text{d}}^d}z\left( 1 \right){\text{d}}\sigma {\sigma ^{ - M}}{e^{ - \sum\limits_{m = 1}^M {\frac{{{{\left\{ {g\left[ {{f^{m - 1}}\left( {z\left( 1 \right)} \right)} \right] - s\left( m \right)} \right\}}^2}}}{{2{\sigma ^2}}}} }}p\left( {\sigma ,z\left( 1 \right),f,g,\Gamma ,d} \right)} } } } } } $

Please, what can you say about those important probability distributions beyond the fact that they should not be invariant by permutation of the time points, i.e. not De Finetti-exchangeable?

What can you say about such strange looking functional integrals (for the state-space and output equations $f$ and $g$) and even set-theoretic integrals (for phase space $\Gamma$) over sets having cardinal at least ${\beth_2}$? Are they already well-known in some branch of mathematics I do not know yet or are they only abstract nonsense?

More generally, I'd like to learn more about functional integrals in probability theory. Any pointer would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is on topic here, and same goes for your other question. If so, [dsp.SE] might be a better choice. But we generally prefer you don't post the same question on multiple SE sites. If the question is off topic here, perhaps we can migrate it to DSP.

Comment: @David. My questions are about (nonlinear) dynamical system theory meeting Bayesian probability theory, both of some tagged in PSE and part of mathematical physics for sure. Therefore, I believe and hope they aren't off topic on PSE. Please provide me some tips on how to make them better fit with PSE. Thanks.

Comment: @David: in my second question http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/251503/ you will see that my story starts with some works by physicist J.D. Scargle from the NASA.

Comment: *this distribution is typically a stochastic process* – That’s like saying that a number is a function.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft. this distribution is typically a stochastic process just means that we have a collection of random variables indexed by the time. I ask what happens if those "random variables" (nothing random here, just Bayesian probability distributions) become functions of the time instead.